How to Archive log4net Logs to an Archive Folder with Date and Time in Filename?
I am using log4net for logging in my .NET application. I need to configure log4net to log to a file until it reaches 10 MB, then move the file to an archive folder within the same base directory. The archived log file should have a filename that includes the date and time, such as log_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.log.
Here is what I have so far in my log4net configuration:
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="Logs/log.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="-1" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <staticLogFileName value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

How can I modify this configuration to achieve the desired behavior of archiving log files to an archive folder with a filename that includes the date and time?
Additional Information:
.NET version: 8
log4net version: 2.0.17
I have configured the RollingFileAppender to roll based on file size and set maxSizeRollBackups to -1 to allow infinite rollbacks. However, this only creates new files in the same directory with sequential numbering (e.g., log.log, log.log.1, etc.).
I expected to find a way to move the rolled log files to an archive folder within the same base directory and name the files using the date and time format (e.g., log_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.log).

Sounds to me like you will have to subclass RollingFileAppender as this is not a built-in feature
